# Add new column to wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I trying update my plugin. So I must upgrade mysql_table. But when trying new column, program get exception.

This is my current table :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE  {$table_name} (
        say_id             int(11)   not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
        customer_mail      text      not null,
        customer_name  text      not null,
        customer_messagge      text      not null,
        messagge_date_time  datetime  not null,

        PRIMARY KEY (say_id)
        )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
        dbDelta($sql);
```

Now I am add colum more one table. I try Alter table, this working one time and add a column but one more refresh I get this error.

This is mycode

```
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
```

And this is my error

WordPress database error: [Duplicate column name 'say_state']
ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1

I see this error and ı try this;

```
$query          = $wpdb->query("select * from wp_customer_say");
        $respond        = mysql_num_fields( $query );
        $column_array   = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < $respond ; $i++):
            $column_array[]     = mysql_field_name($query,$i);
        endfor;

        if( !in_array("say_state",$column_array) ):
            $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
        endif;
```

and I get this error.

```
Warning: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in
```

Help please. Thank you.
Sorry bad english.

Comment: It is because your database does what it was designed for... PERSISTENCE

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this query. I use only mysql-standred for get field name by fast query and this will solve your problem:

```
$row = $wpdb->get_results(  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'wp_customer_say' AND column_name = 'say_state'"  );

if(empty($row)){
   $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide query so i can check what was the problem in your query?

Comment: right answer this. Other answer, if table is empty get error. Thanx

Comment: @MustafaOlkun but above you say that it's not working.. and secondly, under that "incorrect" answer you say `working` :) ) )

Answer (score 6):

You can check column name exists in WordPress using below way,

```
$myCustomer = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_customer_say");
//Add column if not present.
if(!isset($myCustomer->say_state)){
    $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
}
```

Comment: I like this version.

Comment: Nice work, works well. I've added [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691322/2748327) based on this. Basically just worked made sure we don't hardcode anything we don't need to. +1

Comment: I like this one.. Thanks.. +1

Comment: **NO, IT DOESN'T ALWAYS WORK !** It will fail if there are no rows in the table (for example, new table or empty tables).

Comment: Why does this has so many upvotes?..
Doesn't use prefixes and also does a "SELECT *" to check if a column exists :facepalm: you should use "SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{$wpdb->prefix}customer_say' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'say_state' " to check if the column exist..

Answer (score 2):

Best and correct way to add new column into the table if column not exists.

```
/*@ Add status column if not exist */
global $wpdb;
$dbname = $wpdb->dbname;

$marks_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpsp_mark";

 $is_status_col = $wpdb->get_results(  "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`    WHERE `table_name` = '{$marks_table_name}' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '{$dbname}' AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'status'"  );

if( empty($is_status_col) ):
    $add_status_column = "ALTER TABLE `{$marks_table_name}` ADD `status` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `attendance`; ";

    $wpdb->query( $add_status_column );
endif;
```

Comment: This is a great solution for primarily because, unlike the accepted answer [and many others proposed here actually], it does not generate any errors in the debug.log. The accepted answer [and many others], generate this error `WordPress database error Unknown column 'column_name' in 'field list' for query`

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that there's a slightly better way to do this than @Amandeep Wadhawan's answer.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_tables');
function install_tables()
{
    update_options('my_plugins_current_db_version', 0);  // Replace 0 with whatever your final database version is
    // Code here to create the final version of your database tables
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'update_databases');
public function update_databases()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $a_table_to_update = $prefix . $a_table_to_update;

    $current_version = get_option('my_plugins_current_db_version', 0);

    switch($current_version)
    {
        // First update
        case 0:
            // first update code goes here (alter, new table, whatever)
            $current_version++;
        case 1:
            // next update code goes here
            $current_version++;
    }

    update_option('my_plugins_current_db_version', $current_version);

}
```

You just have to make sure that your `install_tables()` function will always create the tables that reflect the final version number and sets the `my_plugins_current_db_version` option to the final version number.

Then in the `update_databases()` function you just have to make sure to increment `$current_version` before each subsequent case.

With this set-up you can blindly update without having to unnecessarily query to find out if columns or tables exist first - and less queries are always a good thing....especially if your update code is firing on the `plugins_loaded` hook.

It is also much cleaner, shows a clear upgrade path, and only executes necessary updates - so it is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Rikesh's option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21331102/2748327) (even upvoted!), but I think to prevent hardcoding information which could change, such as `$table_prefix` from the `wp-config.php` file, this option is a safer bet.

```
// Replace `table_name` with the actual table name
$table = $table_prefix.'table_name';

// And use sprintf to pass the table name
// Alternatively, you can use $table instead of sprintf, 
//     if you use double quotes such as shown here
$myCustomer = $wpdb->get_row( sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 1", $table) );

// If you prefer not using sprintf, make sure you use double quotes
// $myCustomer = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $table LIMIT 1" );

// Replace "missing_field" by the column you wish to add
if(!isset($myCustomer->missing_field)) {
    $wpdb->query( sprintf( "ALTER TABLE %s ADD phone2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL", $table) );

    // Alternate example using variable
    // $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE $table ADD phone2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL") );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a good solution, it works in all cases

```
$check_column = (array) $wpdb->get_results(  "SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = '{$wpdb->prefix}my_table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'some_name'"  )[0];

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
 $check_column = (int) array_shift($check_column);
 if($check_column == 0) {
 $wpdb->query(
    "ALTER TABLE $table_name
       ADD COLUMN `some_name` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL
      ");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myCustomer = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_customer_say");
//Add column if not present.
if(!isset($myCustomer->say_state)){
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ");
```

This code it will fail if you have no records in the database. Only works if you have at least one record saved in your database.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of people in this thread saying they have the best answer, or they have come up with an even better solution....

WordPress has a built-in function for this: **maybe_add_column()**
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_add_column/

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_customer_say';
$column_name = 'say_state';
$create_ddl = "ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD $column_name INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
maybe_add_column($table_name, $column_name, $create_ddl);
```