# mysql query for adding extra column to existing database table for wordpress site

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to add new table and alter the `wp_users` table to add a new column. 
The first SQL is working great i.e creating new table but the 2nd SQL for adding new column is not working. Any help would be great.

Here is the code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "message";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

$sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    user_sender int(11) NOT NULL, 
    user_receiver int(11) NOT NULL, 
    message varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    chat_read tinyint(1) NOT NULL, 
    chat_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

dbDelta($sql);

$sql = "ALTER TABLE $wpdb->users
ADD COLUMN visibility VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AFTER display_name,
ADD COLUMN user_last_activity TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER visibility";

dbDelta($sql);
```

Comment: Hi sorry for last line dbDelta($ql); its dbDelta($sql); but still not working

Comment: Hi thanks buddy I did it with this code

Comment: $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE $wpdb->users 
   ADD COLUMN bpchat_status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AFTER display_name,
   ADD COLUMN bpchat_last_activity TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER bpchat_status");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new column to wordpress database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330932/add-new-column-to-wordpress-database)